# Having issue with Device.Media.pickFromGallery() on Android devices

Tags: smartface.io

I am using `Device.Media.pickFromGallery()` in my app. It's working fine in iOS devices but not working in Android devices. Means, i am getting only the image name which is selected but not complete path as i am getting complete path in iOS. 
I tried with both emulator and installing APK, but the still issue exists.

Can any one help in fixing this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's working on 4.4.0.5. Do check the following code in your project

```
    Device.Media.pickFromGallery({
    type:[SMF.MediaType.image, SMF.MediaType.movie, SMF.MediaType.sound],
    onSuccess:function(e){
    Pages.Page1.Image1.image = e.file;
    alert(e.filename);
    }})
```

Comment: @VijayPrakashDesetty Please up vote my answer your welcome glad I chould help